# Copying a local Array of objects to a instanced array of objects to be accessed by other static methods

Tags: java, arrays, object, pass-by-reference

my question is about creating a copy of a local variable created from within a static method and making it an instanced variable that can be used by other static methods in the class.

Here is the specific part of my code I am having issues with.

```
static void createBooks() {
    Book [] inventory = new Book[maxBooks];
    System.out.println("How many books would you like to add?");
    int newBooks = keyboard.nextInt();
    int createBooks;
    if(newBooks>(maxBooks-findNumberOfCreatedBooks())) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your bookstore has a capacity of " + maxBooks + ", and you have " + findNumberOfCreatedBooks() + " books already created.");
        System.out.println("Therefore we will add a maximum of " + (maxBooks-findNumberOfCreatedBooks()) + " to your collection.");
        createBooks = (maxBooks-findNumberOfCreatedBooks());

    }
    else
        createBooks=newBooks;

    for(int x =findNumberOfCreatedBooks(); x<createBooks;x++) { //creates a new book where one doesn't exist
        System.out.println("***Book"+x+"***");
        System.out.println("Please enter the name this book:");
        String name = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter the author of this book:");
        String author = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter the ISBN of this book:");
        keyboard.nextLine();
        long isbn = keyboard.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Please enter the price of this book:");
        double price = keyboard.nextDouble();

        inventory[x] = new Book(name,author,isbn,price);
    }
```

I am trying to create an array of object Book which can then be accessed by other static methods such as a method called ChangeBooks() which will allow the user to modify books they have created with the setName(),setTitle() etc.

Is there a way to create a instance array of book objects that is changed from a static method, and doesn't point to a null reference when initialized outside the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `inventory` a static field on the class where this method is defined:

```
class BookStuff {
    private static Book[] inventory;
    private static final int MAX_BOOKS = 5;

    static void createBooks() {
        inventory = new Book[MAX_BOOKS];
        // ...
    }

    static void readBook(int index) {
        inventory[index].read();
    }
}
```

Note that an *instance* property cannot be modified by a *class* method (static method).

Comment: Thanks for the help! What I ended up doing was creating the Book [] inventory in the main method and then each static method that needed to use it took it in as a parameter such as:
public static void createBooks(Book [] inventory) {...}